# how should i manage json domain data, nosql or sql solution

Tags: nosql

I've always had this question so I felt I'd just ask.

We have a system which is basically a domain data application. very low usage frequency/volume. From this point, there seems to be no point to use a nosql solution.

On the other side, all our operations are pretty much retrieving an 'object' in json format, and manipulate this set of data base on an object hierarchy. from this front, i really don't see a reason why I would use a relational database to 'model' these objects, then retrieve/translate it into json and back.

So the question really is, how do I justify the use of a nosql based solution? Is it an overkill in the above situation to apply a nosql solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think it is probably overkill to use an SQL solution.

If your data is already in JSON format then why create the extra overhead of converting back and forth?

It all depends on what your expectations are from the chosen database. Performance, Security, Scalability etc.

Based on the information you have given I would be inclined to choose a NoSQL / MultiValue DB solution for compatibility. But if you have special requirements such as scalability or performance then you should throw these into the decision making process. If you need good performance, you can get this with a NoSQL-like solution, even on small hardware.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL or SQL show be used based on a simple question: "Is my data relational?" not "will I have a bunch of data to store?", I think NoSQL answers the question of "how to store information that is clearly non-relational", off course, most of the NoSQL engines are created with the performance and scalability as their main concern, but I think you will not fall into the expression of killing a fly with a hammer in this case.

Something that could be very useful of NoSQL stores is that you will be able to query your information, this will not apply if you use a SQL engines, because they'll treat your json as a blob and those queries will be very difficult to create.

I think you should go to Document store like djondb, MongoDB, Redis, etc which provides query capabilities over your data.